# How to know when to use nommé or qui s'appelle?

Tags: grammaire

How do you know when to use nommé or qui s'appelle?

Eg. If I wanted to say I have a dog named Max, which phrasing would I use and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Nommé* is formal and more "official". It is likely to appear in a legal document, a police report (along with *dénommé* which is often pejorative), or something literary.

> *Un tramway **nommé** Désir* (A Streetcar Named Desire)

*Nommé* can also be used to state someone is appointed to a new position:

> *Edouard Philippe a été **nommé** Premier Ministre.*

In casual speech, *qui s'appelle* is the phrase to use:

> *J'ai un chien **qui s'appelle** Max.*

or, if you only have one dog:

> *Mon chien **s'appelle** Max.*

Using *nommé*  would be understood but is not idiomatic:

> **J'ai un chien nommé Max.*

Comment: "Edouard Philippe a été nommé Premier Ministre." is a different meaning (it cannot give "Edouard Philippe s'est appelé Premier Ministre.").

Comment: @MathieuBouville Yes, that's indeed a different case, the reason why I wrote *also*. "Nomination" was probably not the best term as it only means being in the short list, not necessarily the one selected.

Comment: Nommer is not more formal. It means appoint in English. Except in contexts where it means: named. The streetcar is named Desire.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure to get what you mean. Do you state the French *être nommé* is not more formal than *s'appeller* or are you talking about the English verb *to name*?

Comment: In French, there is no parallelism between nommer et s'appeller. In that sense, it is not "more formal". nommer is to name or to appoint, and s'appeller is used for: My name is x. The OP does not realize that. The terms are used in different contexts altogether, just like English. I have a dog named Max, though, would not be nommer. It would be qui s'appelle Max or dont le nom est Max.

Comment: @Lambie There can be a parallelism: *Il a rencontré un de ses voisins qui s'appelle Guillaume* is standard/casual, *Il a rencontré un de ses voisins nommé Guillaume* is formal/legal. *Astérix a un chien qui s'appelle Idéfix* is common, *Astérix à un chien nommé Idéfix* is formal/literary.

Comment: I don't think the difference is formal/informal necessarily. I think the difference is context. I don't think you can say:  Un tramway qui s'appelle Désir, based on your example nommer/qui s'appelle.

Comment: @Lambie On aurait très bien pu traduire le titre du roman/film par *Un tramway qui s'appelle Désir* ou *Un tramway qu'on appelle Désir* ou *Un tramway appelé Désir*. Il est cependant clair que *nommé* était la meilleure traduction. Voici un exemple qui montre que c'est possible:  [*Deuxièmement, entre la France et l'Allemagne, tout le monde sait qu'il y a **un train qui s'appelle le Thalys** qui fait Paris-Cologne.*](http://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/15/cr-cegrdist/18-19/c1819084.asp)